# How do you add class field description to a OpenAPI/Swagger class?

Tags: .net, .net-core, swagger, openapi

How do you include a class field description in a generated Swagger/OpenApi json?

For example I would like the class properties in the swagger json to include description

```
"properties": {
                 "customerId": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "description": "This is my foo foo foo"
              },
```

I would have expected the code below to produce this result but it does not. It only includes includes `type`

```
public class Customer
{
    [JsonRequired]
    [Description("This is my foo foo foo")]
    public string CustomerId { get; set; } }
}
```

Comment: https://medium.com/c-sharp-progarmming/xml-comments-swagger-net-core-a390942d3329

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this case I was able to use
`[OpenApiProperty(Description = "foo foo")]`